# cx_oracle and oracle 7?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

At work we have Oracle 7. I would like to use python to access the DB.
Has anyone done that or knows how to do it?
I have Windows XP, Python 2.6 and the cx_oracle version for python 2.6

However, when I try to import cx_oracle i get the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed the module could not be found
```

Any help is appreciated!

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cx_Oracle is currently only being provided with linkage to the 9i, 10g, and 11i clients. Install one of these clients and configure it to connect to the Oracle 7 database using the proper ORACLE_SID.

Comment: Ok. We have 9i now but I still get the same error "ImportError: DLL Load failed"

Oracle: 9i
Python: 2.6
Windows: XP SP2
cxOracle: 5.01-py2.6

any more help is again very appreciated!

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Use a tool like [Dependency Walker][1] to track down the missing DLL.

[1]: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: cx_Oracle 4.4.1 seems to be the latest version with 9i support.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the location of the oracle .dll (o files set in your PATH environment variable. The location containing oci.dll should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into that same problem at work.  I finally dropped trying to use cx_Oracle and went with [adodbapi](http://adodbapi.sourceforge.net/).  It worked with Oracle 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ODBC configured then you can use it. It is available with ActivePython or as win32 extensions. You will obtain connection with:

```
connection = odbc.odbc('db_alias/user/passwd')
```

Optionally you can use Jython and thin JDBC client. Instalation of client is not required. With Jython you have access to db via db url:

```
db = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, usr, passwd)
```

where db_url looks like:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:user/passwd@machine_ip:port:dbname
```